# I'm interested in doing some exercises from some books I have, anyone interested in joining?

Tags: discussion, r

I'd like to get better at statistics.  Part of the struggle is figuring out what is important to know and spend time on learning.

That said, I have some light experience with Time Series, and would like to learn more.

I'm considering going through either of these books [Cowpertwait](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387886974)

or [Shumway](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387293175)

Ideally we'd have a handful of people interested , and we could each choose an exercise from a chapter to do, and post that answer.. If you did your answer correct, we could upvote that answer, and thus you would increase your reputation.  I think this actually would add some motivation to do the problems and keep up with the course.

I'm open to any suggestions for what I should do as far as wanting to learn more stats/ what books to learn from, etc.  I'm just putting an idea out there  that I think could possibly work.  I realize most of these ideas fizzle out, but I think with the possibility of having some clever fellow students to learn from, and validly increasing your reputation by solving some difficult problems, I think that it could work.

Thoughts?

I'm also interested in learning about datamining and bayesian stuff as well.

I have access to this book : [Bayes Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387922970)
and this book [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)

at first glance, The elements of statistical learning looks useful but quite challenging.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The area that you are talking about I'm too interested. I've gone through both time-series book & "The Elements of Statistical Learning". The last book is a beauty. If you agree, we can start working on the problems soon.

Rgds,
Ari

Comment: Hi Ari, I am very much interested.  Sorry for the late response.  When would you like to start doing problems?

Comment: Surely. When can we start? And what you want to start with?

Comment: We can start whenever you're ready.  It would be nice if we had a way to share some contact info without posting it on the web.  Is there such a way?  I'd like to start with either time series, or the statistical learning.. You said you'd already done the time series, so I guess let's go with Elements of Stat Learning.